# WordPress Advanced Custom Fields repeater field -- get_field not working for me

Tags: php, wordpress, repeater, custom-fields

Quasi-noob here. I just can't get any result from get_field. Here's my test page:

```
    http://23.21.199.240/test
```

I can retrieve the repeater field data with a FOR loop, but the special ACF get_field function isn't doing what I expected. (It seems so simple, so I won't be surprised if I'm making a totally bonehead mistake.)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: test
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php query_posts('category_name=worldwise&posts_per_page=3'); ?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    id: <?php the_ID(); ?><br />

    <!--let's try to display all the topics (an ACF repeater field) for this post....-->

    <?php if(get_field('topic')): // if there are topics, get all their data in an array ?>

        <?php
            $topic_list_1 = ''; // set up an empty topic list
            while(has_sub_field('topic')): // for every topic 
                $topic_title_1 = get_sub_field('topic_title'); // get the title
                $topic_list_1 .= '<li>' . $topic_title_1 . '</li>'; // and add it to the topic list
            endwhile;  // no more topics, move on
        ?>

        <p><strong>The FOR loop produced these topics:</strong></p>
        <ul><?php echo $topic_list_1; ?></ul>

    <?php else: ?>

        <p style="color:red">GET_FIELD did not find any topics</p>

    <?php endif; ?>

    <!--or, let's try displaying those topics another way....-->

    <?php
        $vid_id = $post->ID;
        $vid_custom = get_post_custom($vid_id);
    ?>

    <?php if($vid_custom['topic'][0] != null): ?>

        <?php
            $topic_list_2 = '';
            for($r=0;$r<$vid_custom['topic'][0];$r++):
                $topic_title_2 = $vid_custom[topic_.$r._topic_title][0];
                $topic_list_2 .= '<li>' . $topic_title_2 . '</li>';                 
            endfor;
        ?>

        <p><strong>The FOR loop produced these topics:</strong></p>
        <ul><?php echo $topic_list_2; ?></ul>

    <?php else: ?>

        <p style="color:red">The FOR loop did not find any topics</p>

    <?php endif; ?>

    <br />

<?php endwhile; else: ?>

    <p>Sorry, no posts or pages matched your criteria.</p>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't like using get_sub_field methods as it gets a bit complicated when you're nesting repeater fields.

This is what's in my opinion the easiest way to get what you're trying to do:

```
<ul>
<?php foreach (get_field('topic') as $row) :?>
    <li><?php print $row['topic_title'] ?></li>                  
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```